Connection Timeout: Cant connect mongo with debezium for CDC
I have mongo and kafka connect set up in docker-compose. I want to enable CDC from mongo with debezium. These are my services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    command: mongod --replSet debezium --bind_ip_all
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
      MONGO_INITDB_FEATURES: "1"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ~/mongos:/data/db

  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: debezium
    hostname: debezium
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kafka
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_configs
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_statuses
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offsets
      KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      ENABLE_DEBEZIUM_SCRIPTING: 'true'
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD',
          'curl',
          '--silent',
          '--fail',
          '-X',
          'GET',
          'http://localhost:8083/connectors',
        ]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

All the other relevant services are working as well since I am already using postgres with debezium. In case of mongo, the connector always returns "Connection Refused". I created a replica set in the mongodb and initialized a user with root privilege:
Initializing Replica Set
rs.initiate({_id: "debezium", members:[{_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]})
Creating User with Permission
use admin
db.createUser({ user: "debezium", pwd: "dbz", roles: ["dbOwner"] })
This is my connector.json:
{
  "name": "mongo-db-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topic.prefix": "dbserver2",
    "mongodb.connection.string": "mongodb://debezium:dbz@mongodb:27017/?replicaSet=debezium",
    "database.include.list": "test",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true"
  }
}


I am able to connect with mongo replica set using the mongodb compass running locally; however, when i run the connector it always returns me, Unable to connect: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint /connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate"}.
I have double checked if the replica set has been initialized correctly as well as the user permissions. I can also create a postgres connector. I am assuming its not a network issue since all of this is in a docker-compose.

Can you try removing container_name from the Mongo service, then [edit] your question to include the corrected config and error message that's  using mongodb in the connection string instead of localhost?

Just did. Is it weird that the error log still gives address=localhost:27017?

Update: restarted everything and the error log changed to address=mongodb:27017; it still gives a timeout error though

Kudos to @OneCricketeer. I have now defined hostname: mongodb within my MongoDB service. Previously, I was also incorrectly defining the replica set:
It was rs.initiate({_id: "debezium", members:[{_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]}); I changed it to rs.initiate({_id: "debezium", members:[{_id: 0, host: "mongodb:27017"}]}) and now it works. For testing purposes, I also removed the debezium:dbz (username:password) in the connection string.

It worked!!!! Thank you so much.
